# Count matching terms in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I am searching in a field with Lucene_35. I would like to get how many words from my term match the field.
For example my field is *"JavaServer Faces (JSF) is a Java-based Web application framework intended to simplify development integration of web-based user interfaces."*, my query term is *"java/jsf/framework/doesnotexist"* and want result 3 since only *"java"*, *"jsf"* and *"framework"* are present in the field.
Here is a simple example I am following:

```
 public void explain(String document, String queryExpr) throws Exception {

        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35);
        Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_35, analyzer);
        IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
        addDoc(w, document);
        w.close();
        String queryExpression = queryExpr;
        Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_35, "title", analyzer).parse(queryExpression);

        System.out.println("Query: " + queryExpression);
        IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(q, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < topDocs.totalHits; i++) {
            ScoreDoc match = topDocs.scoreDocs[i];
            System.out.println("match.score: " + match.score);
            Explanation explanation = searcher.explain(q, match.doc); //#1
            System.out.println("----------");
            Document doc = searcher.doc(match.doc);
            System.out.println(doc.get("title"));
            System.out.println(explanation.toString());
        }
        searcher.close();
    }
```

The output with the above mentioned parameters is:

```
 0.021505041 = (MATCH) product of:
  0.028673388 = (MATCH) sum of:
    0.0064956956 = (MATCH) weight(title:java in 0), product of:
      0.2709602 = queryWeight(title:java), product of:
        0.30685282 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
        0.8830299 = queryNorm
```

....

```
     0.033902764 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(title:framework in 0), product of:
        1.4142135 = tf(termFreq(title:framework)=2)
        0.30685282 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
        0.078125 = fieldNorm(field=title, doc=0)
  0.75 = coord(3/4)
```

I want to get this 3/4 as a result.

Regards!

Comment: How does it relate to Lucene?

Comment: Sorry jpountz, what do you mean? I am using LUCENE_35 and RAMDirectory index. Now I realized that there is a coord factor which gives me exactly what I need but don't know how to get that coord factor.

Comment: Your question didn't mention Lucene, so I wasn't sure what your question had to do with Lucene. Could you edit your question with more details on what you are trying to achieve? How is your index structured? Do you want your documents to be sorted according to the number of matches?

Comment: Edited  jpountz, I hope now is a bit clearer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding Lucene's DefaultSimilarity with the following method definitions:

- computeNorm(field, state) -> state.getBoost()
- tf(freq) -> freq == 0 ? 0 : 1
- idf(docFreq, numDocs) -> 1
- coord(overlap, maxOverlap) -> 1 / maxOverlap
- queryNorm(sumOfQuareWeights) -> 1

This way, the final score of a document ends being the coor factor (1 / maxOverlap) times the number of matching terms.

```
Directory dir = new RAMDirectory();

Similarity similarity = new DefaultSimilarity() {
  @Override
  public float computeNorm(String fld, FieldInvertState state) {
    return state.getBoost();
  }

  @Override
  public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
    return 1f / maxOverlap;
  }

  @Override
  public float idf(int docFreq, int numDocs) {
    return 1f;
  }

  @Override
  public float queryNorm(float sumOfSquaredWeights) {
    return 1f;
  }

  @Override
  public float tf(float freq) {
    return freq == 0f ? 0f : 1f;
  }
};
IndexWriterConfig iwConf = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_35,
    new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35));
iwConf.setSimilarity(similarity);
IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(dir, iwConf);
Document doc = new Document();
Field field = new Field("text", "", Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED);
doc.add(field);
for (String value : Arrays.asList("a b c", "c d", "a b d", "a c d")) {
  field.setValue(value);
  iw.addDocument(doc);
}
iw.commit();
iw.close();

IndexReader ir = IndexReader.open(dir);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(ir);
searcher.setSimilarity(similarity);
BooleanQuery q = new BooleanQuery();
q.add(new TermQuery(new Term("text", "a")), Occur.SHOULD);
q.add(new TermQuery(new Term("text", "b")), Occur.SHOULD);
q.add(new TermQuery(new Term("text", "d")), Occur.SHOULD);

TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(q, 100);
System.out.println(topDocs.totalHits + " results");
ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = topDocs.scoreDocs;
for (int i = 0; i < scoreDocs.length; ++i) {
  int docId = scoreDocs[i].doc;
  float score = scoreDocs[i].score;
  System.out.println(ir.document(docId).get("text") + " -> " + score);
  System.out.println(searcher.explain(q, docId));
}
ir.close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much jpountz! Could you please tell me how to retrieve the result now in my case. It is my first day with Lucine, sorry about it:)

Comment: If you found my answer useful, I would greatly appreciate that you mark it as accepted and/or that you give it an up-vote! :)

Comment: Nice idea, very clever to overwrite the unused similarity calculations to satisfy a need.  This also provides a nice solution for me to a similar problem. Thanks.