# Filter result by number of different matches of the subquery in Elasticsearch or Lucene

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

We want make search query on Elasticsearch that requires at least N different matches of some subquery (or, in simpler case, just several matches of some term).

For example, we want to search for term "test", limit results to documents that has 5 or more occurrences of "test".

Is there any way to make such query or filter on Elasticsearch? I did not find a way.

Is there any way to implement in in Lucene?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484362/count-matching-terms-in-lucene ?

Comment: es 1.0 has a feature called aggregations that might make this easy to do, you can read more here : https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/d9a480c97aa0d5e85c987dd149c1f6f60fd5f7b3/docs/reference/search/aggregations.asciidoc